# Video frames drawn onto canvas only partially visible and magnified

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I have a problem with drawing video frames onto a canvas. I've reporduced my problem in the code snippet below. The problem is that the video frames are drawn onto the canvas but only part of the video frame is visible and that part seems to be magnified a lot (ie. zoomed in).

I suspect that it has something to do with the difference between the width/height properties of the video/canvas elements and the css width and height properties of those same elements, however i cannot get it to work no matter what I try. I tried not setting css width/height at all or only the css width/height, but all produce the same result.

Note that the video itself is 640px by 480px aswell. And when i attach the video element to the dom it display just fine.

```
var video = $('<video />', {
    'width': '640px',
    'height': '480px',
    'muted': 'false',
    'src': 'videos/video1.mp4'
}).css({
    'width': '640px',
    'height': '480px'
});

video[0].load();


video[0].addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
    var canvas = $('<canvas />', {
        'width': '640px',
        'height': '480px'
    }).css({
        'width': '640px',
        'height': '480px'
    });

    canvas.appendTo( document.body );
    var canvasContext = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
    video[0].play();

    var interval = setInterval( function(){
        canvasContext.drawImage( video[0], 0, 0, 640, 480 );
    }, 20 );

    //video.appendTo( document.body );

}, false );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that you're setting the canvas size using css - this is not enough. By default, the canvas has a size of 300x150 - this is the number of pixels it contains. If you wish to make it larger, you need to set the width/height _attributes_ of the canvas - you can't _just_ use css. If you just use css to size it to 640x480, you'll have a canvas that has 300x150 pixels, displayed at a size of 640x480 - i.e it will be a zoomed/cropped view of the top-left corner. Here's a true 640x480 canvas - `<canvas width='640' height='480' id='whatever'></canvas>`

Comment: I would add to @enhzflep's comment that you should avoid hard coding those values and use the `video.videoWidth` and `video.videoHeight` values

Comment: Aren't i setting both the CSS and canvas width in my example?

Comment: Ah my confusion was that I thought that I was setting the canvas width by passing the width and height attributes as arguments to jquery. Appearently these don't set the width and height of the canvas. Instead I had to do: `context.canvas.width = 640;` and `context.canvas.height = 480;`

Answer (score 1):

My confusion was that I thought that I was setting the canvas width by passing the width and height attributes as arguments to jquery like this:

```
var canvas = $('<canvas />', {
    'width': '640px',
    'height': '480px'
});
```

However, appearently this doesn't set the width and height attribute on the canvas tag but seem to set the css width and height. In order to get the right result I had to do:

```
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = 640;
ctx.canvas.height= 480;
```